# react I want to change the background of globalstyle in chakra theme.ts by props

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I want to change the background of the body for each page.
For pageA, I want the backgroud to be white, and for pageB, I want the background to be gray.
I have set the background in the global style of chakra ui, and I want to be able to change the background color in props.

```
// theme.ts
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react';

export const theme = extendTheme({
  styles: {
    global: {
      'html, body': {
        color: 'black',
        background: 'white',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

```
_app.tsx
<ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
  <App />
</ChakraProvider>
```

Comment: That's a good question and sadly, I cannot help you. Your question helped me setting up my background globally though, so thanks for that! Where in the documentation did you find this way of specifying the background?

Answer (score 2):

Chakra is using Emotion under the hood, so the background can be customized for each page using Emotion's `Global` tag as follows:

```js
// pageA.tsx
import { Global, css } from '@emotion/react';

export const PageA: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Global styles={css`body { background-color: hotpink !important; }`} />
      Hello world!
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Whew! This just saved me some hours of digging into chakra's theme trying to solve something like this. Thanks